# Don't execute text file code on response()->file()

Tags: file, laravel-5

In one of my Controllers I am returning a file to the user using the `response()->file()` function. This function displays images if its a `.png`,`.jpg` or `.gif` and text files if it's a `.txt` or `.ini` file.

However, if the file is a `.html` or `.js` file or any other type of file format that has code written in it, *the reponse function will render and execute that code*.

How can I stop laravel from rendering and executing the "text file" that is being displayed?

**EDIT**

I found a perfect solution thanks to [mozammil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7894027/mozammil).

Just tweak your code to something like this

```
    $mimeType = File::mimeType($filePath);

    if($mimeType == 'application/x-httpd-php' OR $mimeType == 'text/html' OR $mimeType == 'text/javascript' OR $mimeType == 'text/css' OR $mimeType == 'application/xhtml+xml' OR $mimeType == 'application/javascript') {
        $mimeType = ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'];
    } else {
        $mimeType = [$mimeType];
    }

    return response()->file($filePath, $mimeType);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a second parameter that will be the headers of the response. You can check the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-responses) for more information.

The following should work

```
return response()->file('test.txt', ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain']);
```

Comment: The problem here being is that I cannot set mime types statically. When the requested file is being pulled up, my script automatically gets the mime type from it. And I really dont want to write hundreds of code to check for each mime type..

Comment: Why do you need to write hundreds of code to get mime type? There's only a select number of files that could potentially be executed, if I understood the question correctly.